# How to determine if function is Checked from IF

Tags: php, optimization, reflection

While working in a project written by some one else ,there's a Function which retrieves some Data's and it's return is the Array with Data.

```
function getSomedata()
{
     //Get some data
     return Array();
}
```

And on the code this function is tested in many Places as

```
if(getSomedata())
  getSomedata();
```

Without editing every piece of code ,can i get notified from **php** if that Function is called from an IF Statement and return a Boolean instead of the Array with Data.

Comment: Even if you find a way to do this, you should not do it. It will make your code so much more difficult to debug, and will give a headache to anyone trying to read your code. Instead why don't you assign the result of `getSomedata()` to a variable, then check if that variable is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, you could use backtracing to figure out which code called a piece of code and read and introspect the code to figure out if the function was called in an `if` statement. But I'm not even going to go into the details of how to do this, because it's utter madness.

`if (function()) function()` is an anti-pattern, broken code, bad, bad, bad. You need to fix this misuse instead of fighting it with more madness. If that's used in a lot of places, bite the bullet and fix it once instead of having to deal with it forever.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best thing you can do is just to use $GLOBALS to check if the Array is set:

```
function getSomedata()
{
    if(!empty($GLOBALS['Arr']))
        return $Arr;

    //Get some data

    return $Arr;

}
```

Something like that... It will work for you if data is not changing during script execution.
But I suggest you to fix your code.